# Ordenar array al hacer un JSON

Tags: php

Quiero ordenar un array que convierto a JSON después de hacer una consulta, como no puedo hacer un order by DESC en la própia consulta tengo que ordernarlo después. Código después de la consulta:

```
$statement = $cnn->prepare( $query );
    //Aquí pasamos $mParams
    $statement->execute($params);
    
    $geojson = array(
        'type' => 'FeatureCollection',
        'features' => array()
    );
    $i = 0;
    while( $line = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $feature = array(
            'type' => 'Feature',
            'id' => $i++,
            'properties' => $data[]=$line,
            'geometry' => json_decode($line['geojson'], true),
        );
        array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
    }
    $statement->closeCursor();
    
    echo json_encode($geojson);
    
    $conexion = null;
```

No se si hay que hacerlo antes del array_push o al hacer el  json_encode.

Comment: Y por qué no puedes hacer un order by en la consulta?

Comment: me daba error al poner ASC o DESC, pero veo ahora que si pongo solamente el ORDER BY, aunque por defecto sea una ordenación ascendente, al ser varios valores , por pantalla parece que los veo como quiero, esto es, el mayor arriba. A lo mejor esto podría valerme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ordenarlo con la función `array_multisort` y el flag `SORT_ASC`  o `SORT_DESC` según sea el caso

Ejemplo: vamos a ordenar el array `$listaMedios` por el campo `Tmedio`

```
<?php
//Este es un array ramdom  deberias rellenarlo con un consulta SQL
$listaMedios = [
  0=>[
    "Nmedio" =>1,
    "Tmedio" =>"el pais"
  ],
  1=>[
    "Nmedio" =>2,
    "Tmedio" =>"ABC"
  ],
  2=>[
    "Nmedio" =>2,
    "Tmedio" =>"ZTv"
  ]
];

array_multisort(array_column($listaMedios, 'Tmedio'), SORT_ASC, $listaMedios);

var_dump($listaMedios);

?>
```

Esta es la salida

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Nmedio"]=>
    int(2)
    ["Tmedio"]=>
    string(3) "ABC"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Nmedio"]=>
    int(1)
    ["Tmedio"]=>
    string(7) "El pais"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Nmedio"]=>
    int(2)
    ["Tmedio"]=>
    string(3) "ZTv"
  }
}
```

Comment: Arreglar un problema que has causado añadiendo más código no suele ser la solución. Lo lógico sería arreglar el problema que está causando que no pueda ordenar en la query, en vez de añadir más trabajo a posteriori